# Play store refunds all users' purchases problem

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

we have a monthly membership application. There is no problem when people sign up for the application and pay money. But yesterday we realized that 3 days and before all memberships are canceled. Can you help if you have experienced such a problem before.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question - this looks like something that only google can answer anyway.

Comment: Is there anyone who had such a problem before is the purpose of asking this question? If so, how did he solve it? Google answer or something else.

Comment: Maybe later someone else will encounter this problem and take immediate action based on the answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use Google Play Billing Library version 2.0 or newer, you must acknowledge all purchases within three days. Failure to properly acknowledge purchases results in those purchases being refunded.

> https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#acknowledge

Google doesn't give you your money even if the purchase takes place. You also need to add unnecessary lines of code to confirm payment

```
if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
        // Grant entitlement to the user.
        ...

        // Acknowledge the purchase if it hasn't already been acknowledged.
        if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
            AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                    .build();
            client.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
        }
    }
```

WTF!!